# unicode error during model inference in Sagemaker notebook

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker, topic-modeling

I am doing inference on a model trained in the sagemaker notebook. I am getting Unicode error while passing the input.

Before deploying, I tried the following and it worked - process the text with input_fn and then pass its output to predict_fn for prediction. But I am facing issue when I use the deploy fn of the sagemaker endpoint.  How can I resolve this.

```
input_text = "BACKGROUND: COVID-19 is associated with pulmonary embolism (PE) in adults."
deployment.predict(json.dumps({"data":input_text}))
```

Error
`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_functions.py", line 93, in wrapper     return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/ml/code/train_nmf.py", line 311, in input_fn     input_data = json.loads(serialized_input_data)   File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 343, in loads     s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')`

Training in Sagemaker Notebook

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn

script_path = 'train_nmf.py'

sklearn = SKLearn(
    entry_point=script_path,
    instance_type="ml.m4.xlarge",
    framework_version="0.23-1",
    py_version="py3",
    role=role,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    output_path=output_data_uri,
    code_location=training_desc_uri,
    source_dir='/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/src')
```

Train NMF Code

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import joblib
import json
CONTENT_TYPE_JSON = "application/json" 

def process_text(text):
    text = [each.lower() for each in text]
    return text

def model_fn(model_dir):
    # SageMaker automatically load the model.tar.gz from the S3 and 
    # mount the folders inside the docker container. The  'model_dir'
    # points to the root of the extracted tar.gz file.
    model = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir, "nmf_model.pkl"))
    return model

def predict_fn(input_data, model):
    # Do your inference
    predicted_topics = model.transform(input_data)
    return predicted_topics

def input_fn(serialized_input_data, model_dir, content_type=CONTENT_TYPE_JSON):
    input_data = json.loads(serialized_input_data)
    input_text_processed = pd.Series(input_data).apply(process_text)
    tf_idf_model = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir, "tf_idf.pkl"))
    processed_sample_text = tf_idf_model.transform(input_text_processed)
    return processed_sample_text

def output_fn(prediction_output, model_dir, accept=CONTENT_TYPE_JSON):
    if accept == CONTENT_TYPE_JSON:
        topic_keywords = joblib.load(
            os.path.join(model_dir, "topic_keywords.pkl")
        )
        pred_dominant_topic = np.argmax(prediction_output, axis=1)
        pred_df = pd.DataFrame(prediction_output, columns=topic_keywords)
        pred_df["dominant_topic"] = pred_dominant_topic
        return json.dumps(pred_df.to_dict("records")), accept
    raise Exception('Unsupported content type')
```

Comment: The error you are seeing is because the serialization/deserialization handled in your inference.py code is not what the model expects. Please refer to the example here (https://github.com/RamVegiraju/SageMaker-Deployment/blob/master/RealTime/Script-Mode/Sklearn/Regression/sklearn-script.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks @RaghuRamesha I included the serializers, deserializer and it worked.